# How to configure Entity Framework Core to map an entity that takes data from two tables with Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

To configure Entity Framework Core, I use the Fluent API. I would like to know if there is some way to map an entity that has some properties related with a table and another properties with another.

It is just for query purposes, to have in one entity the result of the join. In my case I have this entities:

```
class Document
{
   long Id,
   string Name,
   long IdUserLastModification,
   string UserNameLastModification,
   DateTime DateLastModification,
}
```

In my database I have two tables:

- `Document` (IdDocument, Name, IdUserLastModification, DateLastModification)
- `User` (IdUser, Name, Surname, UserName)

In T-SQL I would do in like this:

```
select 
    IdDocument, Name, IdUser, Surname, DateLastModification 
from 
    Documents as d
inner join 
    User as u on u.IdUser = d.IdUserLastModification
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you can add an extension method and field to your entity class to return the filtered document list based on a user id (untested pseudo code follows) and include the UserName as part of your document entity.

```
public partial class Documents //Assuming this is the DbSet
{
    public List<Document> GetDocumentsLastModified(long UserID)
    {
         var result = from d in dbContext.Documents
                 join User as u on d.IdUserLastModification equals u.IdUser
                 select u.UserName, d.*
                 where u.IdUser == UserID;
         return result.ToList();
     }
     [NotMapped] // this keeps the sql generated by EF core to ignore this field otherwise it would include as part of all Document queries
     public string UserName {get; set;} //you could do some of the logic in getter if you include the navigation as explained by others
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dbcontext you can use something like this (LINQ Join):

```
var result = (from ep in dbContext.Documents
                     join u in dbContext.Documents on ep.IdUserLastModification equals u.IdUser
                     select new {
                         UID = u.IdUser,
                         Name = ep.Name,
                         . . .
                     });
```

If you don't, you can always do an SQL query as you just did in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your classes with Navigation properties.

```
public class Document
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public long IdUserLastModification{ get; set; }
    public string UserNameLastModification{ get; set; }
    public DateTime DateLastModification{ get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public long IdUser { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; } = new HashSet<Document>();
}
```

Then configure the relationship in your `DbContext` using fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>(e =>
{
    e.HasKey(d => d.Id);

    e.HasOne(d => d.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.Documents)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdUserLastModification);
});
```

You can then query the data you want using either an anonymous type or a DTO class:

```
var documents = await dbContext.Documents
                .Select(d => new
                {
                    d.Id,
                    d.Name,
                    d.IdUserLastModification,
                    d.User.Surname,
                    d.DateLastModification
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```